# Copy Folder from Structure to new location

Tags: powershell

I have a structure of 900 users like below

User 1
    Personal
        personal.pst

I need to copy the Personal folder from each user folder to a new structure such as below

User 1 (diff username)
    Personal
         Personal.pst

I have a CSV of the User names, so far I have this:

```
$Folders = Import-Csv "C:\drv\users.csv"
$Personal = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folders.OldPath | where {$_.Name -eq "Personal"}  | 
ForEach ($Person in $Personals{
$destination = $Folder.NewPath
Copy-Item -Path $Personal -Destination $destination
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $Personals <> $Personal  check your spelling

Comment: Also $Folders has been assigned, but $Folder has not.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right, try this:

```
$Folders = Import-Csv "C:\drv\users.csv"
foreach ($folder in $Folders)
{
    $Oldpath = $folder.oldpath
    $newpath = $folder.newpath
    $Personal = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder.OldPath | where {$_.Name -eq "Personal"} 
    ForEach ($Person in $Personal)
        { 
        $destination = $Folder.NewPath
        Copy-Item -Path $Person -Destination $destination
    }
}
```